# Selenium: how to set up selenium with web Driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new at writing test-cases for selenium with web driver.

Please let me know how can I set up my test-cases.

Note: I do not want to use Selenium IDE.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have done the set-up myself.. Thanks

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:testContextWeb.xml"})
public class SeleniumTest {

WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.close();
}

@Test
public void testCase() throws Exception {
    //open the event page
    driver.get("https://websiteAddress/Context");


    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='username']")).sendKeys("someUserName");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys("xxxx"); // "xxxx" means some password

 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use selenium webdriver to drive the browser from your code.Start with firefox driver as you don't need any set up for it.For other browsers like chrome,ie you need to setup the drivers.You can get started here :

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example

HTH

Comment: yeah Thanks.. But i do not want to write testcases in a main method.. Any how I have configured the test case to be run with @Test annotations. Thanks for help